# Main form and child form

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt

I am quite new in pyqt design
and I have  a question.

I have a Main form. and a child form.
I want the child form to be opened inside the parent form.

how can I do that in python?

I have written a code that just open the form. 
but it didnot open it inside the form?

Thanks

```
##this method creates an Form Main
class FrmMainForm (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.uiMain = FrmMain.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.uiMain.setupUi(self)
        action = self.uiMain.menuManual_Mode.addAction(self.tr('ManualMode'))
        action.triggered.connect(self.handleNewWindow)

    def handleNewWindow(self):
       ex = Main(self.uiMain)
       ex.show()


class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    white   =  "QWidget { background-color:#FFFFFF }"
    red     =  "QWidget { background-color:#AB0000}"
    green   =  "QWidget { background-color:#00C000}"

    def __init__(self,p):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
       self.p = p
       self.initLogAnalyzerManuall()


    def initLogAnalyzerManuall(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self,self.p)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child window will be garbage-collected when the `handleNewWindow` method returns, and so it will never get the chance to be shown.

You need to keep a reference to the child window, but the way you go about it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Do you literally want a *new* window to be opened every time the button is clicked? If so, then do this:

```
    def handleNewWindow(self):
       ex = Main(self)
       ex.show()

class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    ...
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

On the other hand, if you want the *same* child window to be opened every time, then do this:

```
class FrmMainForm (QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        ...
        self._child_window = None

    def handleNewWindow(self):
       if self._child_window is None:
           self._child_window = Main(self)
       self._child_window.show()

class Main(QtGui.QWidget):
    ...
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
```

Note that in both cases, you can access the main window from the child window with `self.parent()`.